# Java transform JSON to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, json, forms

As an input I have a JSON with the following structure:

```
{
  "amount": 2000,
  "currency": "usd",
  "description": "test charge"
}
```

I need to send a request where this JSON is in **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** content type. So the data should be in this format `amount=2000&currency=usd&description=testcharge`.

My following logic would look like :

1. Parse the JSON to `Map<String, String>` with Gson/Jackson
2. Create a generic method to build key value string

**My first question :** Is there any Java library used for converting a JSON to application/x-www-form-urlencoded? Or isn't there any library for building key value url encoded pairs?

This wouldn't be a big a deal also without library but

**My Second question :** How will look the application/x-www-form-urlencoded query if given json will contain some nested objects/arrays?

```
{
  "amount": 2000,
  "currency": "usd",
  "shipping": {
    "address": {
      "city": "Seattle",
      }
   }
}
```

Would look like? 
`amount=2000&currency=usd&shipping=???`.

That's why I would like to use rather library than my own parsing..

Comment: for your second question: how will the recipient use the transferred data? will it be retransformed to json or will it be used to fill some String values?

Comment: @LalitMehra It will be used for filling the Html FORM String values

Comment: you probably will have to write some conversion and parsing logic this. Might try shipping_address_city as a url parameter